# Prevent tab into field

Tags: javascript, extjs

How can I prevent a user from tabbing into a field (comboxbox)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a field has a tabindex value of -1, it will be skipped when tabbing from field to field.

Answer (score 0):

hm Jacob is right, because i dont know how to set it atm in ExtJs i would go a more complicated way, something like

```
combobox.on('focus', function(){
    var nextField = combo.nextSibling();
    nextField.focus();
});
```